# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not shown even I added in server

Tags: node.js, cors

server side

```js
const express = require("express");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");


const { addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUsersInRoom } = require("./user");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// 2. 라우터 설정
const router = require("./router");

const app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket(PORT);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("소켓 연결 완료");

  socket.on("join", ({ name, room }, callback) => {

    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, name, room });
    if (error) return callback(error); // username taken
 
    socket.join(user.room);
    socket.emit("message", {
      user: "admin",
      text: `${user.name}, welcome to the room ${user.room}`,
    });

    socket.broadcast
      .to(user.room)
      .emit("message", { user: "admin", text: `${user.name}, has joined!` });

    io.to(user.room).emit("roomData", {
      room: user.room,
      users: getUsersInRoom(user.room),
    });

    callback();

  });
 
  socket.on("sendMessage", (message, callback) => {
    const user = getUser(socket.id);
    io.to(user.room).emit("message", { user: user.name, text: message });

    // callback();
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);
    console.log("유저가 떠났습니다..");

    if (user) {
      io.to(user.room).emit("message", {
        user: "Admin",
        text: `${user.name} has left.`,
      });
      io.to(user.room).emit("roomData", {
        room: user.room,
        users: getUsersInRoom(user.room),
      });
    }
  });
});


app.use(router);
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server has started on port ${PORT}`));
```

and this is client side

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import queryString from "query-string";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import "./Chat.css";

// 하위 컴포넌트
import Messages from "../Messages/Messages";
import RoomInfo from "../RoomInfo/RoomInfo";
import Input from "../Input/Input";

let socket;

const Chat = ({ location }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const [users, setUsers] = useState("");

  const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8000/";

  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT); // 소켓 연결

    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    console.log(name, room); // lama peru

    // console.log(socket);
    socket.emit("join", { name, room }, (error) => {
      // console.log("error");
      // 에러 처리
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    });

  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // 서버에서 message 이벤트가 올 경우에 대해서 `on`
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });

    socket.on("roomData", ({ users }) => {
      setUsers(users);
    });
  }, [messages]);

  // 메세지 보내기 함수
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (message) {
      socket.emit("sendMessage", message, setMessage(""));
    }
  };
  console.log(message, messages);
  console.log(users, "users");

  return (
    <div className="chatOuterContainer">
      <div className="chatInnerContainer">
        <div className="appbar"></div>
        <div className="chatScreen">
          <div className="chatScreen">
            <RoomInfo room={room} />
            <div className="messageContainer">
              <Messages messages={messages} name={name} />
            </div>
            <Input message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

and when I try the website I get this
[enter image description here][1]

as you can see there's no Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response header..
I start my project by following.

1. first start server by 'node server.js'
2. start client by command 'yarn start'

the cors options don't seem to apply.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpQ7o.png

would be very thankful if you help me!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS")
    next()
})
```